# What's limiting my file uploads in IIS

Tags: file-transfer, iis

I have a web app that allos users to upload files (using Telerik's RadAsyncUpload control).

My web.config file is set to allow files up to 2Gb and, when I run the app against Visual Studio's built-in web server it runs just fine.

However, if I switch to using IIS (I have IIS 7.5.7600.16385 installed on my machine) files above a certain size simply fails to upload.

I'm still working on identifying the exact upper limit, but I know a file of 60Mb or more won't upload.

My question is: is there anything specific in IIS that I should check/change?

Just to be clear, I have got the following in my web.config file...

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="86400"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, in their infinite wisdom, MS engineers have decided to add a *different* key with a *different* unit of measure to chip in with this.

The following is from the `<configuration><system.webServer>` element of our modified web.config file...

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- This value should be 1024 * maxRequestLength -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

I'd be grateful to hear any comments that suggest I have this wrong, but, at least on the face of it, this seems to work.

Comment: was this in addition to the previous web.config line, or instead of? Glad you appear to solved it for yourself

Comment: As well as. The original value was an attribute of the `<httpruntime>` element. Is this a child of the `<system.webServer>` element